# remove an uploaded file drupal7

Tags: forms, file, drupal-7

I am working with files in a drupal module. I added this form

```
$form['Background_image'] = array(
'#type' => 'managed_file',
'#title' => t('Image'),
 '#progress_message' => t('Please wait...'),
 '#progress_indicator' => 'bar',
'#description' => t('Click "Browse..." to select an image to upload.'),
 '#required' => TRUE,
'#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('jpeg jpg png gif')),
'#upload_location' => 'public://backgroundimage/',
 '#default_value' => $this->options['Background_image'],
);
```

the file is added properly, once the file is uploaded a remove button appears allwoing to remove the file and upload a new one.The problem is that this button is not working so I looked into file module and I found that the hook of removing a file is not implemented yet.

```
function file_file_delete($file) {
 // TODO: Remove references to a file that is in-use.
}
```

How can I remove an uploade file?

Comment: In fact it is my fault the delete function is not not working for "file" but for "managed_file" the remove button is implemented but I have no idea why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

you should use file_delete()
more description here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_delete/7

I will be able to help you more if you post here module version,
maybe it will start working after update :-)

Comment: how can I post it? it is to long because actually I am editing the plugins of the d3 UI module

Comment: that funkcionality which is not working is default drupal functionality, it should work like a charm, if not, try to update drupal core and if it wont help, you will need to play a little with file_delete(). If you still wont be able to figure it out, try to post your source codes on pastebin.com and add here links, I will look at it later today

Comment: yes I know that once the button remove appears it have to work automaticaly without adding extra code because this button is already implemented in the module file so I have only to add the form managed_file and the rest of the work is alreay defined in the file module just like the upload button of the form..The problem is that the remove button work from other modules so no need to update the core!! but still the quetion what is missing?